CKEditor5 pages not saving when attempting to use a relative link to file in body
I'm not sure where to look to troubleshoot this - any advice appreciated.
Drupal 10 w/CKEditor5 as the text editor for the body field on basic pages. Absolute links linked within the body field save just fine, e.g.:
<p><a href="https://mysite.com/sites/default/files/some.pdf" target="_blank">PDF File</a></p>

If we try to add a relative path link, e.g.:
<p><a href="/sites/default/files/some.pdf" target="_blank">PDF File</a></p>

Whether we do this in plain HTML or WYSIWYG (CKEDitor5), the page will not save any edits. IF we take out the relative link to the file and replace with absolute to the exact same file, the page saves just fine.
The weird thing is that relative paths save in the same body field w/CKEDitor 5 in blocks, but not in basic pages. Also, relative paths to pages work totally fine, it's only to files located in the sites/default/files directory.
We do have LinkIt enabled for basic pages, that's the only difference I can find between the block body field and the basic page body field.
Thanks in advance for pointing me in any direction to try and figure this out.

Export config, temporarily uninstall LinkIt, and see what happens.  If the problem disappears then file a bug report with LinkIt.

10.2.5 introduced a really fun bug with the change event not firing reliably, the fact you use LinkIt means there's at least an outside chance it might be related: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3443422. It's easy to test whether this is affecting you: make the desired change(s) in CKEditor, go to the end of the WYSIWYG, press return, press backspace. That will force the previous unreported event(s) to be processed. If the content saves properly after that, you found the problem
